# Safely throwing an exception from a dtor

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++>=11, is it possible to safely throw an exception from a destructor, i.e., only throw it if no exception is already active?

I have tried:

```
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <stdio.h>
struct foo{
    foo();
    ~foo() noexcept(false);
};
foo::foo() { }
foo::~foo() noexcept(false)
{
    if (nullptr==std::current_exception())
       throw 2;
}
int main()
{
    try{
        struct foo f;
#if 1
        throw 1;
#endif
    }catch(int X){
        printf("ex=%d\n", X);
    }
}
```

without success. Am I using the `std::current_exception` function wrong?

I'd like to get `ex=1` if the `throw 1;` part is enabled and `ex=2` otherwise.

Currently I'm getting `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'`
despite the `if` check which, I believe, should have prevented the second throw while an exception was already active.

Comment: Don't do that. Why would you want to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`std::uncaught_exceptions`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/uncaught_exception).

`std::current_exception` returns a pointer to the exception *currently being handled* (i.e. in a `catch` block).

Comment: @PSkocik [This paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4152.pdf) linked at the bottom of the cppreference page explains it. In a nutshell, it's because you can use a `try`/`catch` inside a destructor. In that case, throwing inside the `try` while the destructor is itself called during stack unwinding will lead to *two* exceptions unwinding simultaneously. Letting the second exception escape the destructor is what would cause program termination.

Comment: Note that `std::uncaught_exceptions` only became available in C++17.